# How can I write a spark dataframe to an existing SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I want to use a spark job to pull data from a hive table and then insert it into an existing SQL Server table, flush-and-fill style.

I was planning on using `df.write.jdbc()`, however it seems this method has no way to pass in a `SaveMode.Overwrite` parameter. At the moment, the SaveMode is `ErrorIfExists`.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by this

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").jdbc()
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to truncate the target table but it's not supported by all SQL Server JDBCs (from my experience). As you can see on the code below, you can set the `mode` as `"overwrite"` and later the option `"truncate"` as `true` (where `prop` are the additional properties to set

```
spark.range(10).write.mode("overwrite").option("truncate", true).jdbc(url, "table", prop)
```

Another format for the same is

```
df.write.option("truncate", "true").jdbc(url=DATABASE_URL, table=DATABASE_TABLE, mode="overwrite", properties=DATABASE_PROPERTIES)
```